# Expôr a mesma métrica para o Prometheus porém com timestamps diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, timestamp

Eu quero expor várias métricas com os seus respectivos timestamps para o Prometheus, por exemplo:

```
test5{job_name="test05"} 15 1512982800000
test5{job_name="test05"} 10 1512986400000
test5{job_name="test05"} 6 1512990000000
test5{job_name="test05"} 20 1512990840000
test5{job_name="test05"} 25 1512993000000


test6{job_name="test06"} 2 1512987840000
test6{job_name="test06"} 3 1512991500000
test6{job_name="test06"} 4 1512991800000
test6{job_name="test06"} 5 1512991920000
test6{job_name="test06"} 6 1512992220000
test6{job_name="test06"} 6 1512996000000
test6{job_name="test06"} 7 1512996240000


test7{job_name="test07"} 1 1512909840000


test8{job_name="test08"} 2 1510317840000
```

Porém o Prometheus apenas ingere as métricas que têm um timestamp correspondente a 1 hora antes da hora atual, porquê?

Answer (score -1):

Muito provavelmente as métricas que estão com 1h a menos que atual são os timestamps da máquina que está executando a aplicação do Prometheus.

Se deseja utilizar o timestamp do dado coletado deve ativar a opção `honor_timestamps`, ele controla se devem ser utilizadas as timestamps das métricas. Como diz a [documentação](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

Desta forma em seu arquivo `prometheus.yml` deve ter a configuração `honor_timestamps` no nó `scrape_configs`:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s

# resto das configurações
# ...
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "nginx"
    honor_timestamps: true #<- Adicionar esta opção ***
    metrics_path: /status/format/prometheus
    scheme: http
    follow_redirects: true
    static_configs:
      - targets:
      - localhost:4000
```

Lembrando que este é um arquivo .yml e que espaços são significativos. Então respeite os níveis de endentação na hora de setar as variáveis. Você pode ver um exemplo de configuração completa [aqui](https://danizavtz.com.br/coletando-metricas-de-servicos-com-prometheus/)